# Is there a way to observe when a method from another class is called?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-view

I want to have a custom keyboard class that has different buttons. This class will implement the onClick listener when each button is called but I want another class to handle this event. For example:

```
class Keyboard {
   Button A
   Button B
   ...
   fun onClick() {
      // forward this action to the class that contains me
   }
}

class MainActivity {
   val keyboard = Keyboard()
   keyboard.onClickListener {
      // handle the click events
   }
}
```

How to approach this?

Comment: A standard way would be for the keyboard to *expose events itself* (after doing whatever logic and transformation is relevant), which the main class would listen to. This approach would be “forwarding”. So the code is like 50% of the way there: finish it. (Also, the title appears irrelevant to the body..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to communicate between the `MainActivity` and the `Keyboard` then a callback will do just fine. You could implement it like this:

```
typealias KeyboardCallback = (Button) -> Unit

// Do not recommend doing this, it's for the example only
// It's probably better parsing the keyboard input as Char or Int
enum class Button {
  A, B, C, D
}

class Keyboard {

   private var callback : KeyboardCallback? = null

   fun onKeyPressedListener(listener: KeyboardCallback) {
     callback = listener
   }

   fun onClick(button: Button) {
      // forward this action to the class that contains me
      callback?.invoke(button)
   }
}

class MainActivity {
   val keyboard = Keyboard()
   keyboard.onKeyPressedListener { key: Button ->
      // parse buttons here
   }

   // Somewhere else (Will call the callback)
   keyboard.onClick(Button.A)
}
```

But if you need to listen to the Keyboard from multiples places, then this implementation will not work because as soon as you register a second callback, the first one gets stale (you lose the reference to it, since the `callback` variable can only hold one listener), you can see this problem [here](https://pl.kotl.in/-MK9SEUaG).

If this is ok for your implementation, then do it (it's known as the [Command Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command)**). If it's not, then you need to implement the [Observable/Observer Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer) , which would be more like this:

```
typealias KeyboardCallback = (Button) -> Unit

// Do not recommend doing this, it's for the example only
// It's probably better parsing the keyboard input as Char
enum class Button {
  A, B, C, D
}

class Keyboard {

   private val listeners = ArrayList<KeyboardCallback>()

   fun onKeyPressedListener(listener: KeyboardCallback) {
     callback.add(listener)
   }

   fun onClick(button: Button) {
      // forward this action to the class that contains me
      for (callback in listeners) {
          callback(button)
      }
   }
}

class MainActivity {
   val keyboard = Keyboard()
   keyboard.onKeyPressedListener { key: Button ->
      // parse buttons here
   }

   keyboard.onKeyPressedListener { another: Button ->
       // added another listener
   }

   // Somewhere else (Will call the callback)
   keyboard.onClick(Button.A)
}
```

I've made a simple example for the observable in this [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/TkZ_iPM-4).

** Well, not exactly, it's a simplified version of it, since the command pattern is implemented using a *interface* and a *class* to represent the "command/callback", and that class can store arbitrary state, which the function pointer cannot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create attribute `clickListener` in Keyboard class
2. Create setter for this attribut
3. In your onCLick method in `Keyboard` just call `clickListener?.onClick(buttonClicked)` where `buttonClicked` is button in keyboard which was clicked
4. In your `MainActivity` set listener and handle clickEvent

Example:

```
class Keyboard {
    private var clickListener: View.OnClickListener? = null

    fun setListener(listener: View.OnClickListener) {
        clickListener = listener
    }

    fun onClick() {
        clickListener?.onClick(buttonClicked) // pass button which was clicked
    }
}

class MainActivity {
    private val keyboard = Keyboard()

    init {
        keyboard.setListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //do something
            //it -> button which was clicked
        })
    }
}
```